# Which one to use absolute or relative path?

Tags: jquery, spring, tomcat

I have one web application developed using Spring MVC.
I have a jsp page where I am embedding the same application's page into iframe using an absolute path as below. I deploy the app in tomcat.

Using jQuery on click of tab:

```
$('#iframeId').attr('src', 'http://somehost:8080/maApp/somePath.do?paramOne=us');


<iframe id="iframeId" style="width:90%;height:200px;border:0" src=""></iframe>
```

The above code works only in only windows machine bu fails in unix/linux machine (tomcat).

But if I change it to relative path the it works in both windows and unix/linux.

```
$('#iframeId').attr('src', 'somePath.do?paramOne=us');
```

**Which one should I use, absolute or relative path?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Relative path is a path which is Relative to the actual location of the file that is calling .Basically a relative path assumes that the file is on the "Current server" / "local Server".By using Relative path we can construct our site even offline & can fully test it before uploading files on the server. For Example: "sunlinux\project1\admin\csv\updateshi.php"  .In above example we are giving the actual path where is the file is located on the current server.                                                                                                                                   Absolute path -- An Absolute path is a path which refers to a file on the internet using its full URl.                                                                                          Absolute path tells the browser precisley where to go.                                                           Example-- http:\facebook.com\demouser

So just Use for live servers always absolute path.

Comment: If i use absolute path then it is not working in linux box and it works only in windows.

Comment: There is some problem in path on linux server.check file existence or may be host file.but it is good habit to choose absolute path always.what is the server running where you want to deploy this code

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use `absolute path`, and its up to you you can use any `absolute` or `relative`

But, if you are using any `MVC` then its better to use `absolute path` instead of `relative path`.