# redirect to index page from unauthorized page in php

Tags: php

I have a page that can be accessed once user has logged in. And I want to make a redirect to index page  if the user clicks on the link of the page without logging in. How can this be done?

Btw this is the code i've been trying on and it worked but I just wanna know if this is correct. Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])){ //if login  option in session is not set then

header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Amazingly, when I look for "PHP redirect" on any search engine, there are useful results.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do this by using $_SESSION management.
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
  header('Location:'your path');
  exit;
}
```

just use an absolute path.just see the difference in this post
[Which one to use absolute or relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804802/which-one-to-use-absolute-or-relative-path/22805026#2280502)

Comment: is it okay if i make it like this?<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])){ //if login in session is not set
 
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

Comment: No just checked your already maintained session becauase i think when you authorizing a user then you are creating a session with some name so use it here that session to check or verfiy

Comment: my post is useful for you??

Answer (score 0):

Use Symfony HTTPFoundation component to handle sessions, re-directions, HTTP Request, HTTP Responses and much more.

**THE SHORT ANSWER:**

You can check the session and handle the redirection like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
// ...
if ($request->hasPreviousSession() && $request->getSession()->get('admin_id') {
    $response = new RedirectResponse('http://success.url');
    $response->send();
}
```

**THE LONG ANSWER**

The advantage of using HTTP Foundation vs plain PHP is that you can extend the functionality of your system very easily and separate your code into smaller pieces.

One simple example of extending the functionality "for free" is using a different storage engine for your sessions (Memcached, Mongo, or PDO) instead of the native PHP Sessions.

You can also pair the HTTP Foundation with other components like the Symfony Routing and HTTP Kernel. With these two you can enable your system to

- Have clean URLs
- Described routes using configuration files
- Resolve which classes (controllers) handle specific requests
- Automatically inject request parameters into the controller methods

**Installation:**

Use composer to install this as your project dependency

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/http-foundation": "~2.5"
    }
}
```

**Use:**

Create a `Request` object from the PHP globals like this

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// ...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Create a session and set a value:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
// ...
$session = new Session();
$request->setSession($session);
$request->getSession()->set('admin_id', $id);
```

Before you re-direct a user, check for the session

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
// ...
if ($request->hasPreviousSession() && $request->getSession()->get('admin_id') {
    $response = new RedirectResponse('http://success.url');
    $response->send();
}
```